# Apache Ignite 2.7 release date

Tags: java, maven, ignite

I'm looking for Ignite 2.7 version release date, but there is no information over the web.
On apache site release date is 5 Novermber. But the last version is 2.6.
I've downloaded 2.7 nightly build, but I don't know how to use it with maven.

Comment: Check the developer mailing list for the latest (http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install what you've downloaded, in your local repository. Then you can use it in your project.

```
mvn install:install-file 
    -Dfile=path/to/your/jar.jar 
    -DgroupId=org.apache.ignite
    -DartifactId=ignite-core
    -Dversion=2.7.0 
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

In your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite 2.7 is not released yet. You can track the release process in this thread on the Apache Ignite dev list: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Apache-Ignite-2-7-Last-Mile-td36359i40.html